# How to find roots of equation

Tags: equation-solving

```
Solve[(Cos[θ] - Cos[θi]) + (θ - θi)*Sin[θi] == 0, θ]
```

Hi, I am  new to *Mathematica*, and I am trying to find roots of the above equation, but not success.

Comment: In general, a transcendental equation such as yours will not have closed form solutions. You can use `FindRoot[]` for a specific value of `θi`, along with an initial guess for `θ`, tho.

Comment: Have you tried [FindRoot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html)?

Answer (score 8):

A plot of the equation, which is a form of a numerical solution, is highly suggestive that this is not a "random" equation and might have some structure:

```
eqn = (Cos[θ] - Cos[θi]) + (θ - θi) Sin[θi] == 0;

cplot = ContourPlot[Evaluate@eqn,
 {θ, -20, 20}, {θi, -20, 20},
 FrameLabel -> Automatic,
 GridLines -> {Range[Pi/2 - 7 Pi, 7 Pi, Pi], Range[Pi/2 - 7 Pi, 7 Pi, Pi]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Let's replace `θi` by `θ + u` and see if we can tease out a factor of `u`. Terms in `Sin[u]` can have a `u` factored out thus:

```
Sin[u] -> u Sinc[u]
```

And factors of the form `1 - Cos[u]` can have `u` factored via this transformation:

```
Cos[u] -> 1 - (u^2 Sinc[u]^2)/(1 + Cos[u])
```

We can then factor the function and throw away any factors that do no contain `θ` with [`FactorList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorList.html); factors with a `θ` can be selected with the criterion `! FreeQ[#, θ] &`.

The intermediate steps are irrelevant, so I'll use `%` in the code below (be sure `$HistoryLength` is positive).

```
(Cos[θ] - Cos[θi]) + (θ - θi) Sin[θi] /. θi -> θ + u // TrigExpand;
% /. {Sin[u] -> u Sinc[u], Cos[u] -> 1 - (u^2 Sinc[u]^2)/(1 + Cos[u])};
Select[FactorList@%, ! FreeQ[#, θ] &]
neweqn = %[[1, 1]];
(*  FactorList output -->
 {{-Sin[θ] - Cos[u] Sin[θ] - u Cos[θ] Sinc[u] - u Cos[u] Cos[θ] Sinc[u] +
   Sin[θ] Sinc[u] + Cos[u] Sin[θ] Sinc[u] + u Cos[θ] Sinc[u]^2 + u^2 Sin[θ] Sinc[u]^2, 1}}
*)
```

Now this can be solved:

```
sol = Solve[neweqn == 0, θ]
```

Short form:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are two solutions. Each gives `{θ, θi} == {θ, θ + u}` in terms of `u` and `ArcTan`, which has a branch cut.  On a whim, I thought, "Maybe we can integrate the branch cut."  I'm glad I did, because while the prime motivation was wishful thinking, the solution became a whole lot simpler.

```
dθ = D[Simplify[θ /. First[sol], C[1] == 0], u];
Integrate[dθ, {u, 0, t}]
(*  -(1/2) (1 + π Sqrt[1/t^2]) t + ArcTan[t/(2 - t Cot[t/2])]  *)
```

It still has an `ArcTan`.  We get the same result using the other solution `Last[sol]`.  Solving for an appropriate initial condition, we get a parametrization for `θ`:

```
res = θ -> -(1/2) t + ArcTan[t/(2 - t Cot[t/2])]
```

The branch jumps, reflected in the diagonal red lines, should actually be discontinuities. Apparently they need to be excluded explicitly in `ParametricPlot`. Translating the solution `res` by multiples of `Pi` yields all solutions, except the trivial one `θ == θ1` (corresponding to the factor `u` we took out).

```
Show[cplot, 
 ParametricPlot[{θ, θ + t} /. res, {t, -35, 35}, PlotStyle -> Red]]

Show[cplot,
 ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate@Table[Pi n + {θ, θ + t} /. res, {n, -5, 5}],
  {t, -35.001, 35}, Exclusions -> (2 - t Cot[t/2]) t == 0]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Maybe more can be done, but that's what I got right now.

Comment: Oddball question. How do you get the symbol θ to show up? When I copy from Mathematica and paste into an answer the symbol θ appears as **\\[Theta]**. I see that you have figured a way around this. I couldn't find an answer in Mathematica Meta, indeed they made it sound as if it were not possible.

Comment: @JackLaVigne Two ways: Usually I use [halirutan's toolbar extensions](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor) to convert *Mma* code, but I also have my keyboard set up to switch US/Greek for typing a single character.  You might also be interested in other [site-tools](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-tools).

Comment: This is great! +1

Comment: @ChipHurst Thanks! I've used the differentiate & integrate trick once or twice, but never with such spectacular results.

Answer (score 4):

You can plot your equation as a function of θ for a given θi. You can also find the roots.

In the expressions below I have replaced the symbol θ with x as I was unable to paste it without it showing up as [Theta].

Below `Manipulate` is used to select the value of xi that will be plotted. There are also `Manipulate` parameters for setting the starting value for the two roots.

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   solBig = 
    FindRoot[(Cos[x] - Cos[xi]) + (x - xi)*Sin[xi] == 0, {x, xbig}],
   solSmall = 
    FindRoot[(Cos[x] - Cos[xi]) + (x - xi)*Sin[xi] == 0, {x, xsmall}],

   Show[
    Plot[(Cos[x] - Cos[xi]) + (x - xi)*Sin[xi], {x, -4 π, 4 π},
     PlotRange -> {{-4 π, 4 π}, {-5, 5}},
     PlotStyle -> Black,
     ImageSize -> 400
     ],
    ListPlot[{{x, 0}} /. solBig, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red]],
    ListPlot[{{x, 0}} /. solSmall, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Blue]]
    ]

   }],

 {{xi, -3.}, -4 π, 4 π, Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{xbig, 2.}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{xsmall, -2.}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Open"}
 ]
```

Below is an example with `xi` set to $-3.$ The two solutions (blue and red dots) are $-3.$ and $1.87728$.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Polynomials + trig generally don't mix. See this blog post on [transcendental equations](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/12/18/mathematica-7-johannes-kepler-and-transcendental-roots/).

Your best bet would be to solve over the `Reals` and pick a numerical value for `θi`.

```
With[{θi = π/4},
  Solve[(Cos[θ] - Cos[θi]) + (θ - θi)Sin[θi] == 0, θ, Reals]
]
```

> ```
> {{θ -> π/4}, {θ -> π/4}, 
>  {θ -> Root[{4 Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[2] π - 8 Cos[#1] - 4 Sqrt[2] #1 &, 3.19740930731097365214214291155}]}}
> ```

Comment: They don't mix? That's where the fun begins!

Answer (score 0):

If **" i "** represents the imaginary unit then:

```
eq = (Cos[θ] - Cos[θ I]) + (θ - θ I)*
Sin[θ I] == 0;
sol = FindRoot[eq, {θ, 5 + 5 I}]
```

> $\{\theta \to 2.68471\, +4.77788 i\}$

These equation has infinite solutions:

```
sol2 = Chop@
Table[FindRoot[eq, {θ, n + m I}, 
WorkingPrecision -> 20], {n, -10, 10}, {m, -10, 10}] // Column
```